# Copying to pre-allocated list slower than append which seems counterintuitive

Tags: python

This question has nothing to do with how to copy one list to another. It's about performance. Consider these two functions:

```
def funcA(data):
    A = []
    for d in data:
        A.append(d)
    return A


def funcB(data):
    A = [None] * len(data)
    i = 0
    for d in data:
        A[i] = d
        i += 1
    return A
```

funcA represents what I suppose one might call the *classic* way to copy by reference (ignoring the *copy* module for the sake of this discussion). It's easy to understand and performs extremely well. However, the ultimate size of array **A** is unknown and has to *grow* dynamically as elements are appended to it.

Now consider funcB. It's more complex, **but** array **A** is pre-allocated and items are added by index. I would expect this to be faster because it obviates any memory allocation/reallocation that could occur during appending.

However, I have determined empirically that funcB runs ~30% slower than funcA.

I'm interested to know if anyone has thoughts on why this might be. Below is the driver code I used:

```
from datetime import datetime

M = 1_000
ARRAY_SIZE = 100_000
DATA = [0] * ARRAY_SIZE

for func in [funcA, funcB]:
    _s = datetime.now()
    for _ in range(M):
        func(DATA)
    _e = datetime.now()
    print(f'{_e-_s}')
```

Typical timings are 4.2 seconds for funcA and 5.4 seconds for funcB. This is obviously a CPU-bound activity and therefore results will vary considerably across platforms.

Comment: Are you actually trying to solve the problem of copying quickly? Or are you just wondering about these two specific approaches for a specific reason?  If so, for what reason? If you just want an efficient copy, what's wrong with `data.copy()`? Or `data[:]`? Also, you *are* aware that this kind of thing is implementation-specific, right?

Comment: I am well aware of the optional mechanisms for copying a list. The question is only about why appending is (apparently) faster than assigning to a list of a pre-allocated size

Comment: Don't ever use `datetime.now()` for high percision timing like this. Use `time.process_time()` or `time.perf_counter()` for higher precision in very small timespans

Comment: Also, 1000 is a way too small sample size for performance testing. This will mainly measure how busy the processor is at that specific time.

Comment: @mousetail I changed the iteration count from 1000 to 10000 and also used perf_counter and the performance ratio is identical. The figures are 40.76s and 53.61s respectively. So no difference but thanks for the suggestion anyway

Comment: @mousetail the preferred way to do timing in Python is the `timeit` standard library module.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, even better. Does all my comments for you

Answer (score 2):

Timings on my system, running the reference implementation of Python 3.8, look like:

`FuncA`: 6.0 seconds

`FuncB`: 7.2 seconds

Optimizing `FuncA` by caching the method lookup, thus:

```
def funcD(data):
    A = []
    append = A.append
    for d in data:
        append(d)
    return A
```

4.3 seconds

Using a list comprehension: 2.5 seconds

Using any kind of built-in copy (`data.copy()`, `data[:]`, `list(data)`): 0.9 seconds

It seems pretty clear to me that the bottleneck is in the interpretation of bytecodes.

Your `funcB`, while it avoids resizing the internal storage, needs to fill the memory with copies of the pointer to the `None` object (when the underlying storage is resized normally, the unused portion of the memory can be left uninitialized). A function that just does the `[None] * len(data)` part already takes longer than the built-in copies (under the hood it could be optimized with `memset()` or equivalent, but then the built-ins can use `memcpy()` or equivalent). It also needs to maintain the `i` variable and use it for indexing, and has to interpret bytecodes each time to do so.

Meanwhile, the `list` type uses the same exponential reallocation strategy seen in `std::vector` in C++. Although `funcA` needs to reallocate memory, it only needs to do so O(lg N) times, copying O(N) pointers in total between the allocations.